# Array to BST base case

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I've been trying to wrap my head around recursion with regards to Binary Search Trees
however, I'm having no luck.
Could someone explain to me in the simplest of forms how this block of code (that's widely used from this problem) works on converting an array to a BST:

```
def helper(left, right):
            # base case
            if left > right:
                return None
```

Entire code (taken from leetcode  https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-sorted-array-to-binary-search-tree/discuss/900790/Python3-with-explanation-faster-than-100-PreOrder-traversal)

```
def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> TreeNode:
        # statrt with the middle element and for the right ones go tree.right and for the left ones go tree.left
        # would have to traverse once so the time complexity will be O(n).
        def helper(left, right):
            # base case
            if left > right:
                return None
            
            # get the length to the nearest whole number
            length  = (left + right) // 2
            
            # preOrder traversal
            root = TreeNode(nums[length])
            root.left = helper(left , length -1)
            root.right = helper(length+1, right)
            return root
        
        return helper(0 , len(nums) - 1)
```

Any help on the matter would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`helper(i,j)` is used to convert `array[i:j+1]` to a BST.

```
def helper(left, right):
            # base case
            if left > right:
                return None`
```

This base case is important, because if left index is greater than right index, then logically it isn't possible to create a BST for that. Furthermore, if we don't consider this case and break off the recursion, the algorithm will definitely get stuck in infinite recursion.